# This program is about finding the H.C.F. Can someone help me explain the else block in the following code?

Tags: java, unix

/*This program is about finding the H.C.F. Can someone help me explain the else block in the following code or more precisely explain me the code flow in th eelse block?*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculatingHCF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dividend, divisor;
        int remainder, hcf = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the first number ");
        dividend = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second number ");
        divisor = console.nextInt();

        do {
            remainder = dividend % divisor;

            if (remainder == 0) {
                hcf = divisor;
            } else {                      
                dividend = divisor;
                divisor = remainder;
            }

        } while (remainder != 0);

        System.out.println("HCF: " + hcf);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like the first implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations

Comment: The *code flow in the else block* is precisely: sequential. I.e. do first assignment, do second assignment, block complete. I don't think this is what you really want to get an answer for. Please, rephrase oyur question.